Invalid parameters Failed to deserialize params.partitionKey - BINDINGS: string value expected at position X
This code:
import puppeteer, { KnownDevices, Page } from "npm:puppeteer";
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  executablePath: "C:/Users/ganuo/.cache/puppeteer/chrome/win64-125.0.6422.60/chrome-win64/chrome.exe",
  headless: false,
  userDataDir: "./user_data",
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.emulate(KnownDevices["iPhone 15 Pro"]);
await page.goto("https://m.Facebook.com");

const cookiesPath = "cookies.json";
try {
  await Deno.lstat(cookiesPath);
  const content = await Deno.readTextFile(cookiesPath);
  const cookies = JSON.parse(content);
  if (cookies.length !== 0) {
    await page.setCookie(...cookies);
    console.log("Session has been loaded in the browser");
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  console.log("Create new cookies!");
  const cookies = await page.cookies();
  await Deno.writeTextFile(cookiesPath, JSON.stringify(cookies, null, 2));
  console.log("Session has been saved to " + cookiesPath);
}


runs fine when there is no cookie, but yields this error in the second run:
Warning: Not implemented: ClientRequest.options.createConnection
Cookie exists!
ProtocolError: Protocol error (Network.deleteCookies): Invalid parameters Failed to deserialize params.partitionKey - BINDINGS: string value expected at position 355
    at Callback.<instance_members_initializer> (file:///C:/Users/ganuo/AppData/Local/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/puppeteer-core/23.6.1/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/CallbackRegistry.js:89:14)
    at new Callback (file:///C:/Users/ganuo/AppData/Local/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/puppeteer-core/23.6.1/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/CallbackRegistry.js:93:16)
    at CallbackRegistry.create (file:///C:/Users/ganuo/AppData/Local/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/puppeteer-core/23.6.1/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/CallbackRegistry.js:19:26)
    at Connection._rawSend (file:///C:/Users/ganuo/AppData/Local/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/puppeteer-core/23.6.1/lib/esm/puppeteer/cdp/Connection.js:86:26)
    at CdpCDPSession.send (file:///C:/Users/ganuo/AppData/Local/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/puppeteer-core/23.6.1/lib/esm/puppeteer/cdp/CDPSession.js:63:33)
    at CdpPage.deleteCookie (file:///C:/Users/ganuo/AppData/Local/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/puppeteer-core/23.6.1/lib/esm/puppeteer/cdp/Page.js:493:49)
    at eventLoopTick (ext:core/01_core.js:214:9)
    at async CdpPage.setCookie (file:///C:/Users/ganuo/AppData/Local/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/puppeteer-core/23.6.1/lib/esm/puppeteer/cdp/Page.js:515:9)
    at async readCookie (file:///D:/QC supplements/Code/Apps/Xây nhân hiệu tự động/scr/Puppeteer.ts:54:7)
    at async openBrowser (file:///D:/QC supplements/Code/Apps/Xây nhân hiệu tự động/scr/Puppeteer.ts:81:3) {
  name: "ProtocolError",
  message: "Protocol error (Network.deleteCookies): Invalid parameters Failed to deserialize params.partitionKey - BINDINGS: string value expected at position 355"
}

This similar question doesn't help.
